# ボタンを押すと、別のボタンに対応する処理が行われてしまう

Tags: swift, ios

僕はかなりの初心者なので
ここで質問するのも場違いだと思いますが
失礼します
シンプルなゲームを作ろうとしています

- ボスのHPのラベル(aa)←深い意味はありません
- ボスのHP
- 攻撃ボタン(ss)←ごめんなさい
- 攻撃力ラベル
- 所持金ラベル
- 攻撃UPボタン

などを配置したコードですが
何故か所持金が30未満の時に
攻撃UPボタンを押すと
攻撃ボタンの処理が行われてしまいます
理由がわかる方教えて下さい

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var HP = 100000
    var ATACK = 1
    var UP = 2
    var Mone = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var Powear: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Money: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var aa: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    @IBAction func ss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch HP {
        case 0...100000:
            HP-=ATACK
            aa.text="\(HP)"
            Mone+=5
            Money.text="\(Mone)"

        default:aa.text="\(HP*0)"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func UPButton(_ sender: Any) {
        switch Mone {

        case 30...10000:
            Mone-=30
            Money.text="\(Mone)"
            ATACK*=2
            Powear.text="\(ATACK)"
            HP+=ATACK
            aa.text="\(HP)"
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 攻撃アップボタンの名前 (Name) は何になっていますか？　ストーリーボードなどで確認してみてください。

Comment: 今はまだ一人チームなのかもしれませんが、アプリというのはハードルを何段階か越えて開発が軌道に乗り始めると、すぐに大規模化してしまうものです。チームのメンバーが大人数化する前に(あるいはQAサイトで披露しなければいけなくなる前に)「深い意味はありません」「ごめんなさい」などの言い訳コメントが必要な部分は早めに修正しておきましょう。また、Swiftでは、型名以外の名称(メソッド名やプロパティ名)は小文字スタートにすると言うのがSwift使用者の間で非常によく守られているルールです。そのようなルールにはきっちり従った方が、多くの方に読みやすいコードとなり、結果としてより良い回答をより早く得られることにつながります。で、やっと **本題** ですが、`UIButton`等のコントロールには2個以上のアクションを結びつけることができます。Storyboardを確認して「攻撃UPボタン」のアクションが「攻撃ボタンの処理」(`ss`?)と攻撃アップボタンの処理(`UPButton`?)の両方につながってしまっていないか、確認してみてください。

Comment: 素早い回答ありがとうございます！ メンバーは僕一人だけで一人で勉強してきたのでそのようなルールがあるとは知りませんでした。丁寧にありがとうございます！帰ったら確認してみます！